# STD flexible data structure? c++

Tags: c++, performance, nlohmann-json

I'm using nlohmann json objects, since they can add key-value pairs after runtime (and can readily be serialized)... Though I realize this may sacrifice speed.

Are there any data structures, of similar flexibility, that are from standard c++ libraries?

```
string character_new()
{
    json j;

    j["level"] = 1;
    j["max_hp"] = 2;
    j["hp"] = 2;

    j["skills"] = {
        {"atk", 1},
        {"dex", 1},
    };
    
    j["x"] = 1000;
    j["y"] = 1000;
    j["state"] = -1;
    j["map"] = map_get(MAP::forest);
    j["dead"] = false;
    j["name"] = "Some name";
    //etc

    return(j.dump());
}
```

Comment: `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: Can that handle strings, structs, bools, ints, etc all in one map?

Comment: what kind of speed are you looking for? Read speed/Write speed or both? Does deleting matter?

Comment: `Can that handle strings, structs, bools, ints, etc all in one map?` depends on what template arguments you provide, some types can just be containers to everything else, but overall i don't think there could be anything more "flexible" than that in the standard library

Comment: ***Can that handle strings, structs, bools, ints, etc all in one map?*** Maybe with the help of [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)

Comment: This stuff is stored in a SQL database... So I'm trying to plan ahead, allowing me to add new "stuff" to the function above (that would need to be injected into pre-existing containers loaded from DB). `For read and write speed (if you mean serialization): I don't need to be fast (as it happens rarely) -- Just wanting something for inbetween the read/writes that is decently fast to set/get.`

Comment: I love the JSON flexibility, just want to make sure passing json object references around and changing values (coordinates, hp, whatever) in the main update flow is a good idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the building blocks in the standard but you would have to wrap them up as they will lack the niceties of nlohman and perhaps some functionality too, as serialization.

One general option would be using

```cpp
using AnyMap = std::unordered_map< std::string, std::any >;
```

However std::any is knowingly (and understandably) slow. If you can settle for some few types you can try

```cpp
class Node;
using NodeMap = std::unordered_map<std::string,Node>;
using NodeSequence = std::vector<Node>;
class Node : public std::variant<NodeMap,NodeSequence,long,double,std::string> {};
```

Comment: Hmm, if an any-map is slow, then I guess I might as well stick with the nlohmann objects, avoiding `Read JSON --> any-map --> Write JSON` conversions, assuming nlohmann is similar in speed.

Comment: There is simdjson for parsing and you can use a malloc optimizer like tcmalloc or jemalloc to minimize the impact of node allocation. But typically if you are using json for configuration does it matter that much? You should run some benchmarks.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting task you have! Decided today to implement my own solution from scratch for you, using just standard C++ library.

Following solution is a bit untidy and "might" have some hidden bugs, so better not to use it in production directly without extra testing. But at first glance I did lots of tiny tests and it looks fine.

A bit of untidyness is also in the way code is organized. I didn't make any namespaces and helper classes are located directly inside global namespace. In other words I didn't make final library out of it, but just an educational but fully working example. Sure real library will put all helper code into sub-namespace like `namespace detail { ... }`.

Main core code is a handy class `Any`, it is located not at first position of code, scroll a bit.

Besides this Any class there is one more quite big class `OrderedMap<Key, Value>`. It is a generalization of [std::unordered_map<Key, Value>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), with extra property of all keys being strictly ordered in an order how they were added. So iterating over this map will give always same order equal to order of adding keys.

If you know Python then you would know that Python's `dict()` is ordered too, same like mine OrderedMap<>. Actually I was inspired by this Python implementation.

OrderedMap<> has sub-functionality of std::unordered_map<>, not all methods were implemented.

My OrderedMap<> has same speed as std::unordered_map<>, because it has no extra algorithmical complexity at all. Just a bit it will be slower. Speed is same, because it is based on original std::unordered_map<>, just storing extra iterators to know the order of keys.

This OrderedMap<> is useful because usually when you store config file inside my `Any` then you usually want to preserve same order again and again, but as you know original std::unordered_map<> doesn't preserve order, and may output different order of iteration each time.

Also there is sorted [std::map<>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) in standard library. Although it is always sorted, meaning it will give same order of iteration, still it is not enough, because if you store config files inside Any or JSON, you want some non-sorted order of fields, but strictly given unsorted order.

Now regarding Any class itself.

It models same behaviour as many popular C++ JSON libraries. In fact your testing function `string character_new() { ... }` works with my class with tiny modification.

For educational purposes to make code simpler I made serialization/de-serialization not in JSON format, but my own format. Actually I saw this format one day somewhere, probably first in this D-Lang ["tree.d"](https://github.com/nin-jin/tree.d), see description there. It is very simple format, just a regular tree (graph), where depth of nesting is encoded with repeated tabs (`'\t'` symbol) and each node of tree ends with newline (`'\n'` symbol). That's it, nothing else, very simple...

So tree is encoded like this:

```
root
    childA
        childA0
        childA1
    childB
        childB0
        childB1
```

(in example above all indents are done with tabs `'\t'`).

This tree I use instead of JSON for two reasons - because it is very easy to serialize into such format. And second, more important - it is much more easy and faster to parse than JSON. While still it has a very good visualizing properties, same as JSON. You wanted speed/performance, and this Tree format gives higher peformance than JSON.

In fact this Tree is binary format, not textual. You can store any binary data inside such tree, which is cool! But my class Any converts all data to strings, similar to JSON. Although I can easily modify my code to store it in binary, if more speed or compaction of data is needed.

"Any" itself stores data as

```
std::variant<std::nullopt_t, bool, int64_t, double, std::string,
    std::vector<Any>, std::unordered_map<std::string, Any>>
```

similar as suggest by [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73572921/941531). Except that I put more types inside.

You may wonder what `std::nullopt_t` is - it is basically Null, this type is standard and comes from `#include <optional>` header. `std::nullopt` is constexpr null value itself of type `std::nullopt_t`. I just used it not to invent my own new type like `struct Null {};`, just to signify null value, same like JSON's `null`.

My Any has lots of methods, although not full possible rich range of methods as advanced libraries have. But still most basic methods it has.

Any can be initialized very easily with any type that it supports, so regular use cases look like following:

```
// Just single value
Any x = 123;
x = false;
x = "hello";

// Nested array
x = {2, 3.14, false, true, std::nullopt, "abc", {1, 2 false}};

// Object (map), with nested array and nested object
x = {{"key0", 3.14}, {"key1", true}, {"key2", {{"nested0", 1}, {"nested1", 2}}}, {"key3", {false, true, {{"k0", 5},{"k1", 6}}, 2, 3}}};

// Access integer inside nested arrays and objects with conversion
int y = x["key3"][2]["k0"].GetInt();

// Create new element is easy
x["new_key"] = 456;
x["new_key2"] = {1, 2, false, "msg"};
```

As I said this code is not that ready and clean to be a separate production-ready library. But if you find any bugs, or have suggestions about improvements, please say here in comments.

Unfortunately my code compiles right now only under Windows CLang and MSVC and CLang with [LibC++](https://libcxx.llvm.org/) instead of libstdc++ (use `-stdlib=libc++` option). But doesn't compile under any GCC and Linux CLang with libstdc++. So probably main issue is with GCC's `libstdc++`. Still working on fixing this issue, but decided to post my code an answer already as "almost ready". Also, maybe someone suggests in comments how to fix this right now.

**Update**. Regarding paragraph above, it appeared that my code doesn't compile only under GCC <= 11.3, but compiles successfully under GCC >= 12.1. It happens because native standard library of GCC named libstdc++ doesn't support incomplete (forward-declared) types as Value of std::unordered_map<Key, Value>. But starting from GCC 12.1 it was fixed in libstdc++, and from GCC 12.1 my code compiles, great! To remind, my code compiles already for all quite recent MSVC and CLang (but only if native standard library of CLang called libc++ is used).

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/6cGhxYW41) (GCC/CLang/MSVC)

**FULL CODE HERE**. Due to 30K chars limitation of StackOverflow post unofrtunately I have to provide code on outer services, like Github Gist, code is too large to be inlined here. Also full code is available on GodBolt server if you click `Try it online!` link above.

See [code on Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/polkovnikov/10f53b364c8670a81277e22b5d5e0825) .

Output:

```
o 
    k a
    i 1
    k b
    s xyz
    k dbl
    f 3.140000
    k c
    b false
    k c2
    i 125
    k c3
    b true
    k c4
    n null
    k d
    a 
        s hel\nlo
        n null
        o 
            k key0
            o 
                k skey0
                s hello2
                k skey\n1
                i -123
            k key0.5
            o 
            k key1
            a 
                f 1.230000
                f 4.560000
                b true
            k key1.5
            a 
            k key2
            b false
        a 
            a 
                s key3
                i 123
            s key\n4
            f 4.560000
        o 
            k ab
            s cd
            k x\ny
            f 123.456000
        a 
        o 
        i -123
Most inner0 |f 4.560000|
Most Inner f 4.560000
|i 1|f 3.140000|s xyz|b false|i 125|n null|
double const ref 3.14
double const ref from non-const Any 3.14
double ref 3.14
Dbl x int 3 float 3.14 double 3.14 double ref 3.14
Parsed0 b true
Parsed1 i -12345

Original Test:
o 
    k level
    i 1
    k max_hp
    i 2
    k hp
    i 2
    k skills
    o 
        k atk
        i 1
        k dex
        i 1
    k x
    i 1000
    k y
    i 1000
    k state
    i -1
    k map
    o 
        k key
        s val
        k key2
        i 123
    k dead
    b false
    k name
    s Some name
```